Scan QR code via webcam on Windows 11
Is there a [preferably native] way to scan QR code via my Windows 11 laptop's camera?
I want this in order to easily connect to WiFi via QR codes.

The camera application must be coded to recognize QR codes.  iOS, for instance, didn't always support it. There is no easy solution to this problem.  You will need a third-party application to accomplish your task.

There are third-party tools, such as Bytescout BarCode Reader, which reads both Bar Codes and QR Codes, free for non-commercial use, QR Code Scanner, CodeTwo QR Code Desktop Reader & Generator, etc. These applications work with almost any camera, whether built-in, connected by USB, or otherwise. For that matter, most should be able to read a JPEG, PNG or other image file, without using a camera.
Some of these output the results as text, rather than directly connecting to a site -- copy that text into a browser URL bar, for example. That would be safer than having an app scan a code and blindly connect, which could lead you to malware.
AFAIK, Windows itself does not have a built-in Bar and QR Code app.
Before installing any software, check it at VirusTotal.
